# How do add elements from array into div element where id is equal with array element dealState number in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

[Picture about result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ff9w.png) I have two arrays, one is holding row names

```
arrayForRowNames = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Lead in "
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Contact Made"
  }
]
```

And the other array hold data

```
dataArray = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "bottle sell",
    "value": "100",
    "currency": "default",
    "comment": "cheap deal",
    "dealState": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "[wheel sell][1]",
    "value": "0",
    "currency": "default",
    "comment": "MFD",
    "dealState": "2"
  }
]
```

And i want to make render div row whete the name is "Lead in" and only these titles are going inside that div where `arrayForRowNames "id": 1 == "dealState": "1"` and so on , it has to be dynamical, how can i do it with vue js?

```
<div class="card">
  <h5 class="card-header bd-callout bd-callout-info">                </h5>
               <div class="card-body no-padding">
                    <draggable  element="ul" class="dragArea list-group" :list="arrayName" :options="{group:'a', animation:150}">

<li class="list-group-item ">   
  <button v-on:click="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</button>
                  </li>
               </draggable>
           </div>
       </div>
```

example div what i want to make but i dont know how

```
    <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header bd-callout bd-callout-info">Lead in</h5>
                   <div class="card-body no-padding">
                        <draggable  element="ul" class="dragArea list-group" :list="arrayName" :options="{group:'a', animation:150}">

    <li class="list-group-item ">  
 bottle sell
      <button v-on:click="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</button>
                      </li>
                   </draggable>
               </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: each element in arrayForRowNames  will be rendered into one div, then put `dataArray.filter((item)=>{return item.dealState=arrayForRowNames.id}` as the content for that div?

Comment: can you provide me little example or explain littlebit more?  iam lost at this point.

Comment: I am not sure what you need.So you need to provide one example for the expected output.

Comment: I added picture about what i want

Comment: But in short i need to add different div-s with names from array, it could be done with v-for, but now i dont know how do add li elements with data from dataArray to specific div-s dynamicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below snippet should meet your requirements.

The key point is use `v-for` loop your `arrayForRowNames`, then use element.id (it is card.id in below snippet) to find out all elements whose dealState=element.id from the `dataArray`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      dataArray: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "bottle sell",
          "value": "100",
          "currency": "default",
          "comment": "cheap deal",
          "dealState": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "[wheel sell][1]",
          "value": "0",
          "currency": "default",
          "comment": "MFD",
          "dealState": 2
        }
      ],
      arrayForRowNames: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Lead in "
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Contact Made"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    foundCardDetails: function(id) {
      return this.dataArray.filter((item)=>{ return item && item.dealState === id})
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.card {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="card" v-for="(card, index) in arrayForRowNames" :key="index">
<h3>{{card.name}}</h3>
  <div v-for="(detail, indexDetail) in foundCardDetails(card.id)" :key="indexDetail">
    <span>{{detail.title}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx, that was helpful :P